# Discord.py Cogs “Command [ ] is not found”

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am recoding my discord.py bot using cogs as it wasnt very nice before.

I tried this code:

```
import discord
import os
import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import BucketType, cog, BadArgument, command, cooldown


intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents=intents)
p = ','



class General(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
  
    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.channel.send("I'm **alive**.")

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f'⏱|** {round(bot.latency * 1000)} ms** Latency!')
        await bot.add_cog(General(bot))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    keep_alive.keep_alive()
bot.run(os.environ['token'])
```

But I get an error that says “Command ‘ping’ is not found”. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, and keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum** - we do not [deal in "help"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236), and we want the question to be entirely about **the code, not** you, your level of experience or anything else like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use cogs you usually want to a have a main script. In that main script you load your cogs which are located as separate files in another folder. After you loaded your cogs you will run the bot via the main script.

**Example for main script you can try to copy pasta it:**

Enter your **Token**.

Enter your **Server ID** (-> right click on your server -> "Copy Server ID")

Enter your **APP ID** (-> right click on your Bot -> "Copy User ID")

[image]

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands 
import os 

SERVER_ID = # ENTER YOUR SERVER ID HERE (AS INT)
APP_ID = # ENTER YOUR APP ID HERE (AS INT)
TOKEN = # ENTER YOUR TOKEN HERE (AS STRING)


class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix='.', intents=discord.Intents.all(), application_id=APP_ID)

    async def setup_hook(self):
        for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):  # accessing the cogs folder
            if filename.endswith('.py'):  # checking if cogs inside the folder
                await self.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')  # loading the cogs
        bot.tree.clear_commands(guild=discord.Object(id=SERVER_ID))
        await bot.tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=SERVER_ID))  # syncing the tree in case you use app commands


    async def on_ready(self):
        synced = await self.tree.sync()
        print(" Slash CMDs Synced " + str(len(synced)) + " Commands")
        print(synced)
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name='.helpme'))


bot = MyBot()
bot.run(TOKEN, reconnect=True)
```

Then you need to set up your **cog folder**, for this create a cog folder like this:

[image: cog folder example]

Now you need to put a cog script into the cog folder:

Example for your cog script:

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import BucketType, cog, BadArgument, command, cooldown


class TestCog(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('TestCog loaded.')

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.channel.send("I'm **alive**.")

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f'⏱|** {round(self.bot.latency * 1000)} ms** Latency!')


async def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
    await bot.add_cog(TestCog(bot))
```

Now save the files and run the main script.

I tested it and it worked for me:

[image: testresult]